# Escaping periods in cURL request to REST Api

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am working with a REST API that uses the format http://{server}/api/rest/products/{id}.json as a GET request to get product data. We have a requirement for {id} to contain period characters ("."), which always results in a 404 error because the server cannot interpret it properly. Without the period, the request is fulfilled properly. I have tried replacing the period with %2E, but this is converted back immediately to a period by the server. Is there any way to properly escape the period character for cURL GET requests?

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://" . $server . "/api/rest/products/" . $sku . ".json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: If the API doesn't support it, why not use another character or contact the provider? It sounds like a bug if it allows you to type it into the system, but not use the API.

Comment: problem is server side, you cannot do anything to bypass it

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Thanks. That deals with the root cause. I have access to the API source, so I will probably modify the API to accept a substitute character code that it internally interprets as the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to substitute a different string for the period. I modified the API to do a string replace on the server side, and passed a hexadecimal code ('_0x2E_') from the client side through cURL. The API then performs the string replace to revert to the original value. This functions properly because the server does not see the substituted text as the beginning of a file extension as it did before. The extra underscores and 0x are safety nets.

Adjusted sample code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://" . $server . "/api/rest/products/" . str_replace('.', '_0x2E_', $sku) . ".json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

I hope this is helpful for anyone else dealing with a similar situation.